# get 8 lower significant bits for each element in array

Tags: matlab

I wrote following matlab code to get 8 lsb bits for each element in 1D array.

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

sum=uint32(rand(1,80));
sumf=uint8(zeros(1,80));

for i=1:80        
    sumf(1,i)=bitget(sum(1,i),8:-1:1,'uint32');
end
```

However, when I run, I get following error

```
Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than
non-singleton subscripts

Error in Untitled2 (line 11)
    sumf(1,i)=bitget(sum(1,i),8:-1:1,'uint32');
```

Any suggestions for removing this error ? What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems:

1. `my_uint32 = uint32(rand(1,80))` does not generate random integers. It generates a 1x80 array of uint32s that are either 0 or 1 depending on whether the result of `rand` is returning a double above or below `.5`.
2. You are attempting to assign a 1x8 vector to a uint8. In your case, bitget returns a vector of uint32, eg: `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]`. You cannot assign a vector to a spot in a matrix for a single scalar.
3. `sum` is a standard function in matlab. While you CAN use it as a variable, this is poor style and may be confusing.

   `

I would use a bitwise `and` to extract the 8 least significant digits:

```
random_uint32s  = uint32(floor(rand(1, 80) * (2^32 - 1)));
lsd8 = bitand(random_uint32s, 255); %255 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 + 128

my_uint8 = uint8(lsd8); % if you really want it in a uint8 type for some weird reason?
```

Comment: The whole code is very big. To keep question brief, I used sum array of random . numbers.lsd8 = bitand(random_uint32s, 255) command worked. Thank you so much :-)